# postfix & cyrus-SASL SASLDB2 0: NO "authentication failed"

Tags: centos, postfix, smtp, sasl

We are setting up a Postfix mail relay to accept only authenticated smtp sessions and forward them to our backend smarthosts.

CentOS 6.8
postfix-2.6.6-6.el6_7.1.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.23-15.el6_6.2.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-md5-2.1.23-15.el6_6.2.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-2.1.23-15.el6_6.2.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-plain-2.1.23-15.el6_6.2.x86_64

We have installed and configured Postfix as well as SASL according to a couple of tutorials and references from the postfix manual on postfix.org, although we seem to have a couple of configuration or permission errors. Any help would be appreciated.

---

```
[root@server]# saslpasswd2 -c -u test.com test
Password: test123
Again (for verification): test123

[root@server]# sasldblistusers2
test@test.com: userPassword

[root@server]# testsaslauthd -u test@test.com -p test123
0: NO "authentication failed"

[root@server]# tail -n1 /var/log/messages
Jan 13 08:10:19 server saslauthd[2595]: do_auth         : auth failure: [user=test@test.com] [service=imap] [realm=] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]

[root@server]# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = testing.com
myhostname = smtp.testing.com
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
relayhost = [mx01.testing.com]:25
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relayhost_map
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_fallback_relay = [mx02.testing.com]:25
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtp.testing.com.ca-file
smtp_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtp.testing.com.crt
smtp_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtp.testing.com.key
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP ($mail_version)
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtp.testing.com.ca-file
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtp.testing.com.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtp.testing.com.key
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550

[root@server]# cat /etc/sasl2/smtpd.conf
pwcheck_method: auxprop
auxprop_plugin: sasldb
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5
log_level: 7

[root@server]# cat /etc/postfix/master.cf
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -v
#submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -v
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

SMTP Client Log

```
Stat Connected.
Recv 13/01/2017 8:34:12 AM: 220 smtp.test.com ESMTP (2.6.6)<EOL>
Sent 13/01/2017 8:34:12 AM: EHLO SendSMTPv2.19.0.1<EOL>
Recv 13/01/2017 8:34:12 AM: 250-smtp.securmail.net.au<EOL>250-PIPELINING<EOL>250-SIZE 10240000<EOL>250-VRFY<EOL>250-ETRN<EOL>250-STARTTLS<EOL>250-AUTH LOGIN DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 PLAIN<EOL>250-AUTH=LOGIN DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 PLAIN<EOL>250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES<EOL>250-8BITMIME<EOL>250 DSN<EOL>
Sent 13/01/2017 8:34:12 AM: STARTTLS<EOL>
Recv 13/01/2017 8:34:12 AM: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS<EOL>
Sent 13/01/2017 8:34:12 AM: EHLO SendSMTPv2.19.0.1<EOL>
Recv 13/01/2017 8:34:12 AM: 250-smtp.test.com<EOL>250-PIPELINING<EOL>250-SIZE 10240000<EOL>250-VRFY<EOL>250-ETRN<EOL>250-AUTH LOGIN DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 PLAIN<EOL>250-AUTH=LOGIN DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 PLAIN<EOL>250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES<EOL>250-8BITMIME<EOL>250 DSN<EOL>
Sent 13/01/2017 8:34:12 AM: MAIL FROM:<test@test.com><EOL>
Recv 13/01/2017 8:34:12 AM: 250 2.1.0 Ok<EOL>
Sent 13/01/2017 8:34:12 AM: RCPT TO:<test@testinc.com><EOL>
Recv 13/01/2017 8:34:12 AM: 554 5.7.1 <test@testinc.com>: Relay access denied<EOL>
Sent 13/01/2017 8:34:12 AM: RSET<EOL>
Recv 13/01/2017 8:34:13 AM: 250 2.0.0 Ok<EOL>

[root@Sserver]# tail -n 50 /var/log/maillog
    Jan 13 08:34:23 server/smtpd[13157]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from xx.xx.xx.xx.isp.com[xx.xx.xx.xx]: 554 5.7.1 <test@testinc.com>: Relay access denied; from=<test@test.com> to=<test@testinc.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<SendSMTPv2.19.0.1>
    Jan 13 08:34:23 server/smtpd[13157]: generic_checks: name=reject_unauth_destination status=2
    Jan 13 08:34:23 server/smtpd[13157]: > xx.xx.xx.xx.isp.com[xx.xx.xx.xx]: 554 5.7.1 <test@testinc.com>: Relay access denied
```

Please let me know if any more logs or configuration extracts would be helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd for the relay host usually it is needed to relay mail. Also mydestination try setting it to localhost only and see what happen.
I hope this helps

Comment: I use to relay through outbound.mailhop.org and my sasl_passwd file is set like this outbound.mailhop.org:2525 username:password

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with exim.

You can test with cyrus the username and password on the server shell with e.g.

```
testsaslauthd -u username -r example.com -p secret
```

It does not work with

```
testsaslauthd -u username@example.com -p secret
```

There is further explanation on my post here: [Cyrus sasl error - ''0: NO authentication failed" On Debian 9](https://serverfault.com/questions/934228/cyrus-sasl-error-0-no-authentication-failed-on-debian-9/934239#934239)